# How can I invert BLACK and WHITE (or grayscale) images in tensorflow? (black <->white change)

Tags: python, colors, tensorflow, grayscale, mnist

I want to change some pictures which is consist of black and white elements only (MNIST).

I can easily convert black to white, white to black by these code in python element

```
def inverseImageBW_array(originalImage):
    temp = 1 - originalImage
    temp = -1.* originalImage
    return temp
```

however, I cannot do this when I am treating tensorflow code.
I tried to do this by

```
tf.multiply(1- originalImage, -1)
```

buy it does not work.

I know we can easily change brightness or contrast by tf.image functions but I think there is no functions which support black and white invert.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why something does not work for you. If your image is a 2d tensor or 3d tensor with a batch, then [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting) should take care of everything:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[0.5, 0.3], [0.2, 0.8]])
b = 1 - a
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(b)
```

Comment: yes I know but because tensorflow does not know about the number of input x ( ex. [None, 28, 28, 1] ) . Then they did not do anything, or sometimes occur an error.

Comment: is there any other way to convert black pixels to white, white to black?

Comment: The above solution should work even for inputs of size [None, 28, 28, 1]. Have you tried it?